# Ruby - Get range of month between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I generated a table called `DimensionDate` , which contains all dates between 2011,12,31 and 2032,1,1 .

Now, I would like to know the absolute range of a month between these two dates, for each date.

For example :

2012-01-01 is the number 1 month

2012-02-01 is the number 2 month

2013-01-01 is the number 13 month

2013-02-01 is the number 14 month

2014-01-01 is the number 25 month

2014-02-01 is the number 26 month

etc...

How could I do that ? Any Idea ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
require 'date'

def months_between_dates(date_1, date_2)
  diff_in_years  = (date_1.year-date_2.year)*12
  diff_in_months = date_1.month-date_2.month
  return (diff_in_years + diff_in_months).abs
end

start_date  = Date.new(2011,12,31)
test_date   = Date.new(2013,01,01)
test_date_2 = Date.new(2014,02,01)

p months_between_dates(start_date, test_date)   # => 13
p months_between_dates(start_date, test_date_2) # => 26
```

Edit:

As a bonus here is a version with a default value if you know you will always compare with a specific date. The logic is the same, just short instead of readable:

```
# Call by passing one or two dates:
def delta_months(x, y=Date.new(2011,12,31))
  ((x.year-y.year)*12+(x.month-y.month)).abs 
end

p delta_months(test_date)  # => 13
```

Edit2:

As dax pointed out my function do not provide any form of validation, here is how you would implement that:

```
MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE = Date.new(2011,12,31), Date.new(2032,1,1)
date_range = MIN_DATE..MAX_DATE
test_date  = Date.new(2064,1,1)

raise "Date out of range, must be between #{MIN_DATE} and #{MAX_DATE}." unless date_range.cover? test_date # => Date out of range, must be between 2011-12-31 and 2032-01-01. (RuntimeError)
delta_months(test_date)  # Never called unless good date is provided.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this perfect answer. Everything worked like it should !

Answer (score 1):

[Hirolau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827631/hirolau)'s answer is good but I think this can be made simpler/error proofed.  Since the start time is absolute, you don't need to include it in the method's arguments.  You can test it against the end time as well:

```
def dimensional_date_range(now)
  range = (now.year - 2012)*12 + (now.month)
  if range <= 240 
    range
  else
    "you're out of this dimension, man!"
  end
end
```

tested:

```
$ date =  Date.new(2014,02,01)
$ date2 = Date.new(2050,01,01)
$ dimensional_date_range(date)
 => 26
$ dimensional_date_range(date2)
 => "you're out of this dimension, man!"
```

Comment: I tried to make my function as general as possible and I feel your version have three drawbacks.

 1: The number 240 appears without explanation in the code, and if/when the range changes in the future it will be hard to figure out why, how and if 240 should be changed.

 2: The test for a valid range return a string instead of raising an error. 3: The test does not account for values below minimum date, so if a date below the minimum is passed in the function returns a value instead of raising an error.

Comment: fair enough - i gave you a +1, I think your answer is good.  Just offering other options.  You've made good points, also, so thanks :)